# How to call sequence in Task Scheduler in wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I want to run a proxy(pass through) or a sequence(pass through type) repeatatively after every 60 seconds so i started with Task Scheduler but i am not able to figure out how can i achieve my requirement using Task Scheduler. **I want to execute my proxy or sequence after every 60 seconds.Like in wso2 BPS we can achieve this thing using loops, Likewise is there anything in esb that can schedule run a proxy or sequence after certain interval of time**? Looking forward to your answers.
Thanks in advance.

IS it possible to achieve above requirement in wso2 esb. Please Help.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the task to run a proxy service which is configured in your ESB. You need to configure the task as below.

Here is a sample configuration to access the SimpleStockQuoteService sample service which comes with the ESB. You can replace the value of the "to" property to match your proxy endpoint and set the desired message.

```
<task class="org.apache.synapse.startup.tasks.MessageInjector" name="CheckPrice">
 <property name="to" value="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService"/>
 <property name="soapAction" value="urn:getQuote"/>
 <property name="message">
               <m0:getQuote xmlns:m0="http://services.samples">
                   <m0:request>
                       <m0:symbol>IBM</m0:symbol>
                   </m0:request>
               </m0:getQuote>
       </property>
       <trigger interval="5"/>
</task>
```

Comment: I have a operation as urn:UpdateCache in my service hosted in axis2.In this service i am getting data from wso2 dss and putting it to cache. So i want to call only this service with the operation name and it doesn't have any input request

Comment: Then you can just send an empty message body.

Answer (score 0):

Form WSO2 ESB version 4.7.0 new properties are added to task component. Using those we can call a proxy service or sequence from our task scheduler. Below are my sample code for calling a proxy service

```
<task name="DBPOller"
         class="org.apache.synapse.startup.tasks.MessageInjector"
         group="synapse.simple.quartz">
      <trigger count="2" interval="5"/>
      <property xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"
                name="soapAction"
                value="urn:getRequestForm"/>
      <property xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks" name="message">
         <p:getRequestForm xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"><!--Exactly 1 occurrence--><p:isRead>n</p:isRead>
         </p:getRequestForm>
      </property>
      <property xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"
                name="injectTo"
                value="proxy"/>
      <property xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"
                name="proxyName"
                value="DBPollerService"/>
   </task>
```